# Use of the word "multiple"

Tags: meaning, connotation

Multiple definition - 
">"having or involving several parts, elements, or members

Several definition - 
">"more than two but not many

```
                                                           _via Google Search_
```

Multiple definition - 
">"something in units of more than one or two

```
                                                           _via Webster_
```

Can I use the word multiple to mean exactly two things? I know it is not clear and can even be sneaky, but would it be flat out wrong? Would I be lying or simply abusing the word (or would I be well within my rights) if I said I had multiple cookies in the jar when really only two were left in the jar?

Comment: Maybe he’s playing a guessing game and wants to be sneaky.  MW says “more than one” https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multiple

Answer (score 4):

As Jim's comment says, [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multiple)'s definition is as follows:

> **Multiple**
>
> 1. consisting of, including, or involving more than one.

However, [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/multiple)'s definition leans towards suggesting a larger number is implied:

> **Multiple**
>
> 1. Having or involving several parts, elements, or members.
>
>    > 1.1  Numerous and often varied.

So, probably safe to say that although it wouldn't be a complete lie to use the word "multiple" to mean "two", it would be quite misleading to the reader. Whether you use it or not depends on your intentions.

Answer (score 2):

Describing two cookies as “multiple cookies” is factually incorrect : a lie, if asserted deliberately. This follows not from the minimum number required, but from the indefiniteness required. Some writers consider *multiple* to begin at one, others at two, but they are quite consistent about using it only when the quantity is not definitely known. Nobody that I am aware of would use it of a known quantity. This has been true ever since the word was borrowed from Latin. Consider the following sentences in which the author contrasted a *multiple* quantity with a *known* quantity:

> (1647) That Kings should bow down their necks under the double or rather multiple yoke of Pope and Archbishops.
>
> (1797) M. Magellan thinks, that the aphronitrum is not only a triple but a multiple salt.
>
> (1867) The double and multiple stars shine with differently-coloured light.

If you want to avoid the lie, maybe the best you could do is to say the cookie jar holds multiple cookies (a statement about its capacity, not its contents).

Sentences taken from *A New English Dictionary on Historical Principles*, [volume VI: M–N](https://archive.org/details/oed6barch): 1902. (This source includes plenty of historical examples of the use of *multiple* to mean “two or more”, so that usage is well established and cannot be called wrong.)

Comment: I don't know if I would say that "multiple" in general has to mean the number is not definitively known, but I agree that it does if it's intended to mean "more than one". I can imagine using it for more than two or three things where the number is known, but not important.

Comment: 'Describing two cookies as “multiple cookies” is factually incorrect' is an absolutely shocking statement to make. You state that nobody you know would make that assertion, but this has no bearing on whether it is logically true. Perhaps you are thinking purely of American English speakers? See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multiple#Adjective